# http outbound gateway is sending only one request at a time

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a http outbound gateway that is connecting to one URL. Below is the code snippet. I am dropping around 100 files on the folder. The URL connects localhost:8080/index.jsp. In the JSP i have added Thread.sleep(60000).

When I run the code I see that only one call is made to JSP every 60 seconds. However my pool manager to have 25 connections per route.

Not sure why it is not working. Anyone has faced similar problem?

```
    <int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50"/>

          <int:channel id="inputChannel">
            <int:queue  capacity="5"/>
          </int:channel>

          <int:channel id="httpInputChannel">
            <int:queue  capacity="5"/>
          </int:channel>

        <int-http:outbound-gateway id="simpleHttpGateway"
            request-channel="httpInputChannel" 
            url="${app.webservice.url}"
            http-method="GET"
            extract-request-payload="false"
            expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
            charset="UTF-8"
            reply-timeout="1234"
            request-factory="requestFactory"
            reply-channel="wsResponseChannel">
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>

        <bean id="requestFactory"
              class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
        </bean>

         <bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient">
            <constructor-arg ref="poolManager"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="poolManager" class="org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager">
            <property name="defaultMaxPerRoute" value="25"/>
            <property name="maxTotal" value="250"/>
        </bean>
      <int:channel id="wsResponseChannel">
            <int:queue  capacity="5"/>
        </int:channel>

        <int:service-activator ref="clientServiceActivator" method="handleServiceResult" input-channel="wsResponseChannel" />

        <bean id="clientServiceActivator" class="com.spijb.serviceactivator.ClientServiceActivator"/>

        <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="producer-file-adapter" channel="inputChannel" directory="file:c://Temp//throttling" prevent-duplicates="true"> 
            <int:poller fixed-rate="100" /> 
        </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

        <int-file:file-to-string-transformer
            id="file-2-string-transformer" input-channel="inputChannel"
            output-channel="httpInputChannel" charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: How many request handling threads do your have? If that is just 1 you are basically doing it yourself. Why do you even have a `Thread.sleep` in your JSP? Just log a message stating that something was received instead of blocking the request handling on the server.

Comment: There are around 10 threads on the tomcat server. I just added thread.sleep to prove that only one request was hitting the tomcat server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single poller thread on your file inbound channel adapter. You need to add a task-executor to the poller, with a pool size set the number of concurrent requests you want to handle.

You also need to set `max-messages-per-poll`, which defaults to 1.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the response. I am bit new to SI. Is it possible to help me with some links that would help me to understand this better.

Comment: Don't use all those `<queue/>` channels - since you have a task executor on your main poller; you can simply use direct channels dowstream of it.

Comment: Gary, the only reason I added queue channel is that I read that direct channel would execute in the same thread. From Spring docs: "In addition to being the simplest point-to-point channel option, one of its most important features is that it enables a single thread to perform the operations on "both sides" of the channel. For example, if a handler is subscribed to a DirectChannel, then sending a Message to that channel will trigger invocation of that handler's handleMessage(Message) method directly in the sender's thread, before the send() method invocation can return."

Comment: I think the solution works fine whether I use direct channel or queue channel only when I assign executor to default poller. I think http outbound gateway internally uses the default poller and hence it has to be provided with executor. Please confirm if my understanding is correct. Thanks a lot for your help so far.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but with all those queue channels you have too many (and unnecessary) thread hand-offs. As I said, since your initial poller now has a task executor, it is not necessary to use queue channels; the whole flow can run on the executor's thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary for the clarification and help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the configuration to add executor as below.

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="producer-file-adapter" channel="inputChannel" directory="file:c://Temp//throttling" prevent-duplicates="true"> 
        <int:poller fixed-rate="100" task-executor="executor" max-messages-per-poll="25"/> 
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="25"/>
```

Still it was only sending one request to my tomcat server listening for index.jsp. My understanding was if there are multiple messages present in the channel queue which is the case now on httpInputChannel, the http outbound gateway would process multiple requests. However this is not happening. I further changed my default poller as below.

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50" task-executor="executor"/>
```

After above change, the http outbound gateway started sending multiple requests to the URL. Now I am confused. Do we need to explicitly assign executor for outbound gateway to process multiple messages at the same time? Can someone please direct me to the documentation for the same?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't add an answer to add clarification; delete this and edit the question instead.

Comment: You were using the default single-thread poller for the queue channels - which are not needed when you have an executor on the file poller.